# Install Ubuntu's font in other OSes?

Tags: ubuntu, fonts

Ubuntu has its own font for its UI in the past couple of releases.

Is there a way to get this font in other GNU/Linux distros? Does the font come in its own file?

Comment: if you're wanting to use Ubuntu font on a website/webapp, then note that the [Ubuntu font is in Google Web Font](http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Ubuntu) for usage in CSS font-face.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referring to [Ubuntu Font Family](http://font.ubuntu.com/), then yes it is available to other distributions (for example, there is an [Arch package in the AUR](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=41465)), but it would be equally straightforward to download it and install it manually if a package wasn't available for your distro.

The font is here: http://font.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu-font-family-0.71.2.zip

Comment: Yep -- I've actually seen it used in an android app as well.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can use it other OSes and distros. It may be available as a package on your distro (hard to know without knowing which one). If not, you can dowload a .zip file that contains all the variations of the font (in ttf format) [here](http://font.ubuntu.com/).